# Java substring not working

Tags: java, string

Forgive me, I'm new to Java and have an extremely basic question. I have a string and want a substring of it, for example:

```
String str = "hello";
str.substring(1);
System.out.println(str);
```

Instead of getting `"ello"` I get the original `"hello"`, any idea why this is? Thanks.

Comment: you are printing out your original string. you are not assigning the value of the substring to anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strings cannot be changed in Java, so you will need to re-assign the substring as such:

```
str = str.substring(1)
```

as opposed to calling the method by itself.

Comment: Ah I see, calling the method by itself just throws away the result.

Comment: Well, when you call substring(), it doesn't modify the string, but returns a modified version of the string.

Answer (score 12):

Strings in Java are immutable. I believe you want to do this:

```
String str = "hello";
str = str.substring(1);
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't saving the changes done on the string.

```
str=str.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the substring into a new variable (or the old one if you prefer). Something like this should do the trick:

```
String str = "hello";
String strSub = str.substring(1);
System.out.println(strSub);
```

For people reading this post, remember that substring(1) means take the substring starting at char 1 and going until the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly put it in the *.println(..)*

```
String str = "hello";
System.out.println(str.substring(1));
```

but *str* will remain unchanged.